# Cocoa ignore clicks but still register them?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, onclick, mouseevent, event-propagation

Is it possible to have a click-through window in cocoa (as in `_window.ignoreMouseEvents = TRUE`), but still find out when the mouse has been clicked above the window? Or, instead of ignoring the events, registering them, and then somehow forwarding them, propagating them to whatever is behind the window?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the NSView method hitTest.
This method is called on every view when a mouse click is received.

```
- (NSView*)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    return self;
}
```

Returning self would mean that the click is not forwarded to the next subviews.

Returning [super hitTest] would just forward the click to the parent view of your view hierarchy. Using this, you could simply register clicks without anything else happening.

So something like:

```
- (NSView*)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    [self propagateEventToNextApplication];
    return [super hitTest:aPoint];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem, however, is how to do that propagation to the next application. I also thought about tracking the global mouse actions, but I only found NSMouseMovedMask for the global events, not NSMouseClickedMask or something of such kind.

Comment: Still, this might help you. If you can manage to get the last view (which is the content view of the window) to ignore the click events, they may get forwarded to the next application. I've never tried it, but it might work.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. But I achieved the results in another way. I made the window click-through and made a global event handler for mouse left/right mouse button clicking. That way, I still know if the mouse has been clicked above the window, and the clicks are automatically redirected to the 'layer' below.